# IIS 8.5 Perl CGI User Impersonation failing

Tags: perl, iis, cgi, windows-authentication, impersonation

Environment - IIS 8.5 (Windows 2012) via CgiModule mapped to activeperl x64 executable, windows authentication, anonymous authentication disabled

I'm trying to perform admin tasks on a domain server from a perl cgi script.  I'm connecting as a domain user with full admin rights to the remote server.  When I run the script via command line it works, but as CGI it fails with permission denied.  I have verified in taskmanager that perl.exe runs under my domain account when I run it from IIS.  On the remote server, I see that NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON tries to authenticate and fails.  Somewhere in IIS the CGI 'Impersonate User' flag is not working correctly.

**UPDATE 4/14/2014**

My band-aid solution is to run the application pool as a service account and to set 'Impersonate User' to *false* in CGI settings of the site.  I would still like to be able to run CGI scripts as the windows authenticated user via impersonation.